# XQuery - Doing math on elements within a sequence and aggregating results

Tags: function, operators, xquery, sequence, aggregation

I'm trying to execute a XQuery sum function in a multiplication of two XML elements, but it has been difficult to avoid the iteration in a sequence of elements. For example, consider this case:

sample data:

```
<Orders>
     <Order>
        <OrderKey>1</OrderKey>
        <LineItem>
          <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
          <Quantity>41</Quantity>
          <ExtendedPrice>70848.0000</ExtendedPrice>
          <Discount>0.0913</Discount>
          <Tax>0.0663</Tax>
          <ReturnFlag>A</ReturnFlag>
          <LineStatus>F</LineStatus>
          <ShipDate>1994-09-03</ShipDate>
        </LineItem>
        <LineItem>
          <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
          <Quantity>44</Quantity>
          <ExtendedPrice>64372.0000</ExtendedPrice>
          <Discount>0.0674</Discount>
          <Tax>0.0145</Tax>
          <ReturnFlag>A</ReturnFlag>
          <LineStatus>F</LineStatus>
          <ShipDate>1994-08-18</ShipDate>
        </LineItem>
        <LineItem>
          <LineNumber>3</LineNumber>
          <Quantity>41</Quantity>
          <ExtendedPrice>64247.0000</ExtendedPrice>
          <Discount>0.0396</Discount>
          <Tax>0.0466</Tax>
          <ReturnFlag>R</ReturnFlag>
          <LineStatus>F</LineStatus>
          <ShipDate>1994-10-21</ShipDate>
        </LineItem>
      </Order>
      . . . 
</Orders>
```

XQuery:

```
<results> {
   for $lineitem in collection("tpch")/Orders/Order/LineItem
   let $returnflag := $lineitem/ReturnFlag 
   let $linestatus := $lineitem/LineStatus
   where $lineitem/ShipDate <= "1998-08-31"
   group by $returnflag, $linestatus
   order by $returnflag, $linestatus
   return
   <record>
      <l_returnflag>{$returnflag}</l_returnflag>
      <l_linestatus>{$linestatus}</l_linestatus>
      <sum_qty>{sum($lineitem/Quantity)}</sum_qty>
      <sum_base_price>{sum($lineitem/ExtendedPrice)}</sum_base_price>
      <sum_disc_price>{sum($lineitem/ExtendedPrice*(1-$lineitem/Discount))}</sum_disc_price>
      <sum_charge>{sum($lineitem/ExtendedPrice*(1-$lineitem/Discount)*(1+$lineitem/Tax))}</sum_charge>
      <avg_qt>{avg($lineitem/Quantity)}</avg_qt>
      <avg_price>{avg($lineitem/ExtendedPrice)}</avg_price>
      <avg_disc>{avg($lineitem/Discount)}</avg_disc>
      <count_order>{count($lineitem)}</count_order>
   </record>
} </results>
```

BaseX output:

[XPTY0004] Item expected, sequence found: (element ExtendedPrice {...}, ......

When I removed "sum_disc_price ..." and "sum_charge ..." result lines, the query runs normally.

My question:
Considering this dataset model, how can I to write this query without change its semantics?

Comment: FYI, you can put your data _into_ your XQuery using `declare context element`, to have something folks can copy/paste/run as a single document.

Comment: ...copy/paste/run would also mean taking the `collection()` out.

Comment: Actually -- the `group by` is messing you up too, because it means that `$lineitem` can refer to more than one `LineItem` at a time. I don't know how you'd expect your math to work when `$lineitem/Discount` refers to two separate discounts at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occurring because you're using operations (like multiplication) that take exactly two arguments, and passing a sequence on one side or both. To illustrate the meaning of the error -- you get the exact same thing running:

```
(1,2,3) * 2
```

---

Since your goal is to multiply values together within each individual `LineItem` inside the `$lineitem` sequence (which is a sequence due to the `group by` operator) before aggregating the results, you *could* use `fn:for-each-pair`. Implemented with an anonymous function, one might do the following:

```
      <sum_disc_price>{sum(fn:for-each-pair(
        $lineitem/ExtendedPrice, $lineitem/Discount,
         function ($price, $discount) as xs:double {
           xs:double($price) * (1 - xs:double($discount))
         }(?,?)))}</sum_disc_price>
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense, because without the group by the query combines all possibilities. I just need to list the total of discounted extended price and the total of discounted extended price plus tax of all LineItems.

Comment: You need to split out where you're doing your group math (avg, etc) from where you're doing your individual-item math. Do the math on individual items first, then iterate over the results of that and do your grouping and aggregation later.

Comment: Multiplying `ExtendedPrice * Discount` doesn't make sense when both `ExtendedPrice` and `Discount` are sequences with more than one item, after all. Sure, you *want* it to multiple the first element of ExtendedPrice against the first element of Discount, second against the second, etc; but there are so many other ways the system could interpret that, so the language doesn't allow it: you need to write your code to disambiguate.

Comment: @LuizMatos, ...actually, fn:for-each-pair might be what you want here.

Comment: It works (without taking out the group by)! Thank you @CharlesDuffy.

Comment: And supposing that I could not use local function. Do you have other idea? The xquery processor's grammar that I use is limited. :/

Comment: Sure -- the other approach is to use an anonymous function. I've edited appropriately.

Comment: I mean any "function" reference even "fn:for-each-pair" or "function ..".

Comment: Oh. If you don't have XQuery 3.0, then you'll need to nest two different FLWOR expressions -- do the individual-item work on the inner one, and the grouping on the outer one. But... if you don't have XQuery 3.0, are you sure you even have `group by`?